# Trace zero means matrix is nilpotent?

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

I have to prove or disprove:

> If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for any prime number $p$ and the trace of any power of $A$ is $0$, then the matrix is nilpotent: $A^k = 0$ for some positive integer $k$.

I'm not sure where to go with this. But I don't think this statement is true Are there any good counterexamples?

Comment: Please note, for further reference, the $\LaTeX$ editing I did to your post.

Comment: For it to be true, the characteristic of the field needs to be 0.

Answer (score 5):

Think of the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix for $p = 2$. Generalize.

Comment: If p is not prime, does the identity matrix serve a good counter-example for p=4 for example? Because I^2=I still in Z/4Z.

Comment: Furthermore, the trace of a 2 x 2 identity matrix is not 0, it's 2.

Comment: When $p=2$, $2=0$, user.

Comment: Oops, I just forgot that the matrix is in Z/pZ. Thanks, Gerry Myerson.

Comment: @user332740 Not only that: $p=4\;$ isn't a prime number, which is a given in your question.

Comment: I'm aware that p=4 isn't prime, I was asking earlier about Z/4Z because I don't know why the counterexample by Andreas Caranti wouldn't work in Z/4Z ... why p must be prime and why we can't have any integer k...

Comment: As I said, generalize. If you take the $n \times n$ identity matrix, it will have trace $n$, which is zero modulo any $k$ that divides $n$.